Geting UnicodeDecodeError in then run read_sql_query for PostgreSQL
I make database by this code:
CREATE DATABASE "new_db"
WITH 
OWNER "postgres"
ENCODING 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
TEMPLATE template0;

Successfully added table:
CREATE TABLE public.rounds
(
    rounds_id bigint NOT NULL,
    rounds_bot_date date,
    rounds_bot_time time without time zone,
    PRIMARY KEY (rounds_id)
)

In Python I create engine:
db_config = {'user': 'postgres',
             'pwd': '****',
             'host': 'localhost',
             'port': 5432,
             'db': 'new_db'}

connection_string = f"postgresql://{db_config['user']}:{db_config['pwd']}@{db_config['host']}:{db_config['port']}/{db_config['db']}"
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

And then I try run pandas.read_sql_query:
pd.read_sql_query('select * from rounds', con=engine) 

I get this error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 61: invalid continuation byte

Same thing, then I try to append data to table.
I think there's coding mistake in database.
Or correct connection_string.
I also tryed use postgresql+pg8000, but get another  error:
ProgrammingError: (pg8000.dbapi.ProgrammingError) {'S': '�����', 'V': 'FATAL', 'C': '28P01',

With "postgresql+psycopg" error:
OperationalError: (psycopg.OperationalError) connection failed: ������������ "postgres" ��

I also tryed this thing:
import ssl
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
engine = create_engine(
    connection_string,
    connect_args={"ssl_context": ssl_context},
)

And get this error:
InterfaceError: (pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError) Server refuses SSL

P. S. Database contains only english content.
P. S. S. Same query perfectly runs in DBeaver.
Python ver. 3.11.7
Pandas ver. 2.2.1
SQLAlchemy ver. 2.0.25
PostgreSQL ver. 16.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1937, 64-bit

run engine.execute("SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';") and try to query again

I get error "'Engine' object has no attribute 'execute'". =(

what driver package do you use?

SQLAlchemy ver. 2.0.25, maybe I need downgrade it?

can you try this please? with engine.connect() as connection:     connection.execute("SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';")

I get just the same error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2.

I've just reinstall Postgres, the same version.
Connection I used:
db_config = {'user': 'postgres',
             'pwd': '****',
             'host': 'localhost',
             'port': 5432,
             'db': 'db_new'}

connection_string = f"postgresql+pg8000://{db_config['user']}:{db_config['pwd']}@{db_config['host']}:{db_config['port']}/{db_config['db']}"
engine = create_engine(connection_string, client_encoding='utf8')

I don't know that's the difference, but now it's works.
